# Ordering or sorting objects in state [React JS]

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is a function that adds objects `product` to `products` in state

```
addProductToCart(productId, productName)
{
  var product = {
    id: productId,
    name: productName,
  };

  this.setState({
    products: {
      ...this.state.products,
      [product.id]: product
    }
  });
}
```

but these objects are sorted by [product.id]. How do I sort them in the order they are added to the cart?

Comment: Any particular reason why are you keeping items as unordered map instead of array? If you had a state in the shape of `[product1, product2]` and reducer which would add it like so `[...this.state.products, newProduct]` then they would be ordered as they are

Comment: I use it because it is easy to remove a `product` from `products` using `delete this.state.products[id];` Is there something similar for arrays?

Comment: Not THAT easy, but simple enough. Since your `id` is a key, we can treat is uniquely; and we can use `filter` on a array to do the job. let's use function defined as `function productsWithoutGivenIdPredicate(id) {return (product)=>product.id!==id}}` and use it like so: `var productsWithDeletedItem = productsInBasket.filter(productsWithoutGivenIdPredicate(__SOMEID__))`

Answer (score 0):

maintain one more array `ids` in which, you can append the productIds as they are added :

```
addProductToCart(productId, productName)
{
  var product = {
    id: productId,
    name: productName,
  };

  this.setState({
    products: {
      ...this.state.products,
      [product.id]: product
    },
    productIds : [...ids, product.id]
  });
}
```

You can then iterate over the array to retrieve the product in the order of their insertion.

Answer (score 0):

If you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33351962/2630817) objects are by default key value pairs,

You have 2 options you can use @Easwar solution or you can use array instead to store.
As far as I see your strucutre there is nothing wrong in using the array structure for your requirement.

You should restructure your state like this

```
 constructor() {
    super();
    this.addProductToCart = this.addProductToCart.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      products: []
    };
  }

  addProductToCart() {
    productsId--;
    var product = {
      id: productsId,
      name: 'test',
    };   

    this.setState({
      products: [...this.state.products,product]      
    });
  }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8n5a37)

As I can see you have a problem getting removed object from array you can use this easily

```
removefromCart(value) {

    var array = [...this.state.products]; // make a separate copy of the array
    var index = array.findIndex(a => a.id === value);
    if (index !== -1) {
      array.splice(index, 1);
      this.setState({ products: array });
    }
  }
```