# Is there any option to order form.value in a custom way in Angular?

Tags: angular

I am practicing template-driven forms in Angular. Below is the example of this simple form.

```js
import { NgForm } from "@angular/forms";

onSubmit(form: NgForm): void {
  console.log(form.value);
}
```

```html
<form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm)">
  Username:
  <input type="text" name="user_name" ngModel/>
  Password:
  <input type="password" name="password" ngModel/>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The default way of logging to the console is like the following,

> password: "123456" user_name: "shah"

But I want the keys should be shown according to the order in the form, like this,

> user_name: "shah" password: "123456"

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent automatic sort of Object numeric property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33351816/how-to-prevent-automatic-sort-of-object-numeric-property)

Answer (score 1):

Object in Javascript doesn't have an order.

You can use a FormArray, which internally has sort functionality.

Or if you really wany to do it with object, you probably have to store your controls inside an array and change the order