# Group by array of objects in TypeScript without sorting

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm working on an array of object to group them according to the key(number), but it always ends up sorting the array. So is there any solution using Map() to perform group by or any TypeScript solution for it.

```
const reGroup = (list, key) => {
    const newGroup = {};
    list.forEach(item => {
        const newItem = Object.assign({}, item);
        newGroup[item[key]] = newGroup[item[key]] || [];
        newGroup[item[key]].push(newItem);
    });
    return newGroup;
};
const pets = [
    {type:"Dog", age: "5", name:"Spot", },
    {type:"Cat", age: "3", name:"Tiger",},
    {type:"Dog", age: "2", name:"Rover",  }, 
    {type:"Cat", age: "3", name:"Leo", }
];

const grouped = reGroup(pets, "age");
console.log(grouped);
```

Output:

```
       {
     "2": [ { "type": "Dog", "age": "2", "name": "Rover" } ],
     "3": [ { "type": "Cat", "age": "3", "name": "Tiger" },
           { "type": "Cat", "age": "3", "name": "Leo" } ],
     "5": [ { "type": "Dog", "age": "5", "name": "Spot" } ]
     }
```

Expected:

```
       {        
         "5": [ { "type": "Dog", "age": "5", "name": "Spot" } ],
         "3": [ { "type": "Cat", "age": "3", "name": "Tiger" },
               { "type": "Cat", "age": "3", "name": "Leo" } ],
         "2": [ { "type": "Dog", "age": "2", "name": "Rover" } ],
         }
```

Comment: You should not rely on the order of object properties in JavaScript. Historically, object properties were unordered, and even though a defined order has since been introduced, the logic is complex and contains a lot of special cases. One such special case is that numerical keys are sorted numerically.

Comment: If you need an order, keep the array.

Comment: Atleast in Typescript is there any way to achieve it

Comment: keep the array, but how can I get the desired output

Comment: Do you want a solution using the array? basically grouping your output inside an array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent automatic sort of Object numeric property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33351816/how-to-prevent-automatic-sort-of-object-numeric-property)

Comment: If you desire a specific order you most likely want to use an array and not an object. Use an array, that hold objects, one property can be your index and the content could be another. That's reliable.

Comment: If you have a key for each object, why do you need to sort it anyway? You can access by the key.

Answer (score 1):

Use an array instead of an object. Order of keys in objects cannot be guaranteed.

Try:

```
  const reGroup = (list, key) => {
    const groups = [];
    list.forEach(item => {
        let groupIndex = groups.findIndex((gi) => gi.key === item[key]);
        if (groupIndex === -1) {
          // when the group containing object does not exist in the array, 
          // create it
          groups.push({key: item[key], items: []});
          groupIndex = groups.length - 1;
        }
        const newItem = Object.assign({}, item);
        groups[groupIndex].items.push(newItem);
    });
    return groups;
  };
  const pets = [
      {type:"Dog", age: "5", name:"Spot", },
      {type:"Cat", age: "3", name:"Tiger",},
      {type:"Dog", age: "2", name:"Rover",  }, 
      {type:"Cat", age: "3", name:"Leo", }
  ];

  const grouped = reGroup(pets, "age");
  console.log(JSON.stringify(grouped, null, 2));
```

which logs:

```
[
  {
    "key": "5",
    "items": [
      {
        "type": "Dog",
        "age": "5",
        "name": "Spot"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "3",
    "items": [
      {
        "type": "Cat",
        "age": "3",
        "name": "Tiger"
      },
      {
        "type": "Cat",
        "age": "3",
        "name": "Leo"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "2",
    "items": [
      {
        "type": "Dog",
        "age": "2",
        "name": "Rover"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```